# How to get magento API call response in browser

Tags: php, rest, api, curl, magento2

I gave up after 2 days. I want to get list of all products from magento2 api in browser. First I tried "http://mydomain.con/index.php/rest/V1/products?Authorization=Bearer_TOKENHERE?searchCriteria=" but it didn’t work (still not authenticated). The next thing I’ve tried was to call api with php curl:

```js
<?php
//test for 1 product
//API URL for authentication
$apiURL="http://mydomain.con/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token";

//parameters passing with URL
$data = array("username" => "test", "password" => "123456qwe");
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init($apiURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json","Content-Length: ".strlen($data_string)));
$token = curl_exec($ch);

//decoding generated token and saving it in a variable
$token=json_decode($token);

//******************************************//

//Using above token into header
$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer ".$token);

//API URL to get all Magento 2 modules
$requestUrl='http://mydomain.con/index.php/rest/V1/products/24-MB01';

$ch = curl_init($requestUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//decoding result
$result=json_decode($result);

//printing result

print_r($requestUrl);

print_r($result);

?>
```

Unfortunately, this call get me a perfect answer in terminal in php storm (id, name, sku, price, etc in json) but if I want to get answer by browser it shows me Error 404 Request URL not found in server (when file is actually uploaded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a problem somewhere in web server. Check .htaccess in document root and host config in apache.

Comment: Ok, but what I must to looking for?

Comment: give more details like filepath on server, document root and contents of host config & .htaccess. It may be some typo or rewrite rule

Comment: I dont think it may be this problem, cuz all magento2.1 project is uploded to my server from gitlab, only some basic configuration was make- like admin path, admin acc etc. 
But also this is weird, my fellow mate who also has domain in this server, can get api in browser with same code :/

Comment: i am not even sure if your problem is related to magento. you didn’t mentioned filepath/name of this api client script. according to its contents it is outside of magento context/code.

Comment: folder with script is inside root folder (server_url/HOME/mydomain/DOMAINS/PUBLIC_HTML(this is root folder)/src/apicall.php)

Comment: debug it with a simple die('test'); at the top of your script. if you still get 404, then it is web-server, dns or browser related

Comment: Yep i still got 404.
But if i move file directly to root folder (public_html/apicall.php) i got "File not found"

Comment: add something like ini_set('display_errors', 1); to get full error message. If "file not found" comes from curl it may be a dns issue

Comment: already added ini_set('display_errors', 1); , 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); , 
error_reporting(E_ALL); . Nothing.

Comment: It looks like apache server has disabled paths.

Comment: Yep, path enabled and apache server response now. Thanks for any help.

Comment: as i said web server issue. upvote and accept if i helped